# kill mysql query in perl

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a perl script in which i create a table from the existing mysql databases. I have hundreds of databases and tables in each database contains millions of records, because of this, sometimes, query takes hours because of problems with indexing, and sometimes i run out disk space due to improper joins. Is there a way i can kill the query in the same script watching for memory consumption and execution time?

P.S. I am using DBI module in perl for mysql interface

Comment: Does [`kill`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) useful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used KILL QUERY command as described in http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=885620

This is the code from my script

```
eval {
    eval { # Time out and interrupt work
        my $TimeOut=Sys::SigAction::set_sig_handler('ALRM',sub {
            $dbh->clone()->do("KILL QUERY ".$dbh->{"mysql_thread_id"});
            die "TIMEOUT\n";
        });
        #Set alarm
        alarm($seconds);
        $sth->execute();
        # Clear alarm
        #alarm(0);
    };
    # Prevent race condition
    alarm(0);
    die "$@" if $@;
};
```

This code kills the query and also removes all the temporary tables

Answer (score 2):

As far as execution time, you use `alarm` Perl functionaility to time out.

Your ALRM handle can either `die` (see example below), or issue a DBI `cancel` call (`sub { $sth->cancel };`)

The [DBI documentation](http://p3rl.org/DBI#Signal_Handling_and_Canceling_Operations) actually has a very good discussion of this as well as examples:

```
  eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "TIMEOUT\n" }; # N.B. \n required
    eval {
      alarm($seconds);
      ... code to execute with timeout here (which may die) ...
    };
    # outer eval catches alarm that might fire JUST before this alarm(0)
    alarm(0);  # cancel alarm (if code ran fast)
    die "$@" if $@;
  };
  if ( $@ eq "TIMEOUT\n" ) { ... }
  elsif ($@) { ... } # some other error
```

As far as watching for memory, you just need for ALRM handler - instead of simply dying/cancelling - first checks the memory consumption of your script.

I won't go into details of how to measure memory consumption since it's an unrelated question that was likely already answered comprehensively on SO, but you can use `size()` method from `Proc::ProcessTable` [as described in the Perlmonks snippet *Find memory usage of perl program*](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=235757).

Answer (score 1):

Watch out that you can't kill a query, using the same connection handler if you have a query that is stuck because of a table lock. You must open another connection with the same user and will that thread id.

Of course, you have to store in a hash the list of currently opened thread ids.

Mind that once you've terminated a thread id, the rest of the Perl code will execute .. on a unblessed handler.